# Configuring the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I can run the ASP.NET Web Site Administration tool. Under the Security tab, I can enable roles. And then I can add roles. Seems to work very easily.

Just one small detail: which database is it adding roles to? Certainly not the one I'm working on. Guess I just modified some other database on my system. I can't see anywhere in this tool where it tells me which database I'm working with. Is this a gross oversight or am I just missing something fundamental here?

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0(v=vs.100).aspx, no mention is made of how to determine which database this tool is working with. So it must just be me that doesn't know this automatically.

So can someone please bring me up to speed?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?  And what membership provider are you using?  The web site configuration tool only works with the old SqlMembershipProvider and will not work with SimpleMembership, Universal providers, etc..

Comment: I'm using the latest version of MVC. I'm not yet using any membership provider. I was just going to start by populating the database. And I was probably going to just use the default membership provider that comes with ASP.NET. I have no idea what SimpleMembership is.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about SimpleMembership though. Looks like I need to read up on that.

Comment: Well, the web site administration tool will not work with the membership provider that comes with MVC4.  The tables are totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your web config for your connection strings. Then also check your web config for your membership and role providers and check what connection string they are using.

Eg:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="CHECK HERE!!" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: There's no `<membership>` entry in my web.config. Surely, this must be documented somewhere.